# elementary OS 'Loki' Shutdown doesn't work :(

Tags: shutdown

I just installed the latest version of elementary OS 'Loki' available on the web and I have been updated something from the App Center, the problem is that when I click the power button and then the red power button, computer stops working itself, but the screen is illuminated with the elementary logo and does not turn off the whole pc, how can I fix it?

I do not want to be having to shut down the computer by pressing the physical button ...

Thanks ;)

---

The main problem is when i try to shutdown (pressing the red button from the menu) the pc turns off, but the monitor is still on and illuminated with the elementary logo, only sometimes the shutdown works at 100%

:(

Comment: What happens if you press `space` or `ctrl`+`alt`+`f1`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is happening there when you press the Shutdown button on the top right corner, but you can always shutdown by opening the terminal and type `shutdown -h now`

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same problem I had shutdown -h now won't help. I had to edit a config file fore grup before the problem went away.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/7114/why-cant-i-restart-shutdown

The firs solution worked for me, but read further down in the linked page to get some more spesifics on how to edit the file.

Comment: Could you write down here what should be done, please?